# SQL Server script not working as expected

Tags: sql-server

I have this little script that shall return the first number in a column of type int which is not used yet.

```sql
SELECT t1.plu + 1 AS plu
FROM tovary t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tovary t2 WHERE t2.plu = t1.plu + 1)
  AND t1.plu > 0;
```

this returns the unused numbers like

1. 3
2. 11
3. 22
4. 27
   ...

The problem is, that when I make a simple select like

```sql
SELECT plu
FROM tovary
WHERE plu > 0
ORDER BY plu ASC;
```

the results are

1. 1
2. 2
3. 10
4. 20
   ...

Why the first script isn't returning some of free numbers like 4, 5, 6 and so on?

Comment: Your query can't return rows that don't exist. If your table has no row with the number 3, there's no way for it to produce 4. This kind of problem is known as "islands and gaps" and searching on that term should give you plenty of reference material.

Comment: There is no row `3` in your table `t1`, so it's impossible to check if it has the value `4` in your table, because that relies on the value `3` existing. The same with 5 and 4, 6 and 5, etc, etc.

Comment: @JeroenMostert clearly in the first result there is the number 3 and in the second it doesn't show, so the guy either didn't explain well, you didn't understand well, or he made up the result numbers.

Comment: The reason there is a `3` in the first result, @Ineffable21, is because that's `2 + 1`. `t1.plu + 1` means that `t1.plu` *can't* be equal to `3` as `3 + 1 = 4`.

Comment: @Larnu yes, of course I missed the possibility of me not understanding :). Thanks

Comment: It seems what the OP *really* needs here is an (inline) Numbers/Tally (table) which they can then use a `NOT EXISTS` against their table.

Comment: @JeroenMostert and Larnu - true didnt notice it... big face palm here :D .... thanks for explanation.

Comment: You can not return that number which are not available in table. In first query you are not displaying Original number you are displaying number by adding 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compiling a [formal answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments-or-extended-in-chat) from the comments.

Credit to [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74640416/sql-server-script-not-working-as-expected#comment131747812_74640416):

> It seems what the OP really needs here is an (inline) Numbers/Tally (table) which they can then use a NOT EXISTS against their table.

### Sample data

```
create table tovary
(
  plu int
);

insert into tovary (plu) values
(1),
(2),
(10),
(20);
```

### Solution

Isolating the [tally table](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql) in a [common table expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql) `First1000` to produce the numbers 1 to 1000. The amount of generated numbers can be scaled up as needed.

```
with First1000(n) as
(
    select row_number() over(order by (select null))
    from       ( values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0) ) a(n) -- 10^1
    cross join ( values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0) ) b(n) -- 10^2
    cross join ( values (0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0) ) c(n) -- 10^3
)
select top 20 f.n as Missing
from First1000 f
where not exists (  select 'x'
                    from tovary
                    where plu = f.n);
```

Using `top 20` in the query above to limit the output. This gives:

```
Missing
-------
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
21
22
23
24
```